# What are the parameters for "printto" using shellexecute?

Tags: delphi, winapi, printing, shellexecute

I'm using Delphi's winapi ShellExecute to try to print to a user selected printer and not the default printer.  I'm trying to figure out the syntax for a command using the printto verb.

What would an example shell execute statement look like if I wanted to print manual.pdf to a HP Laser Jet 4 with IP address 192.168.1.49?

(this is just an example, but if you can help me out, I can take it from there)

Comment: Perhaps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776883(VS.85).aspx can be of use?

Comment: Yeah, I found something non-useful on MSDN yesterday and thought that was the last word on the matter.  Thanks!

Comment: Pass the network network address of the printer in the arguments parameter

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the network network address of the printer in the arguments parameter.

```
ShellExecute(
  WindowHandle,
  'printto',
  PChar(DocumentName),
  PChar(PrinterNetworkAddress),
  nil,
  SW_HIDE
);
```

Comment: How do you get the network address address / what's the difference between that and what is returned as the port int Printer.GetPrinter?  mjn's code works for me, but I'd rather use this.